# Html page should always fit on screen no matter of display size

Tags: html

On my screen at my workplace the content of my page always fits perfectly. But when I go to our meeting room there is a big screen and there page does not fit anymore. Then a scroll bar appears on the right side. So I have to zoom to 80% and now it fits again. But ideally the page would fit all the time no matter how big screen is.

How can I achieve this. My html page starts with a html tag inside this there is head and body tag. Would it help to have a style in html tag which sets padding, border, and margin to 0 ?

Comment: Can you share the code needed to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases this is worked solution:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

But it depends on your content size in some cases it's not possible to fit content to some screen size (if content has more vertical height than screen height) so you should make responsive design/css

[image]

Comment: I tried it and it did not work. Because of overflow:hidden the content that did not fit the screen was cut off and was not viewable at all. So this is not an option. What I want is the following. Right now when I go to our meeting room I have to press Ctrl -  till it reaches 60%  , that's what I want automatically done , if you now understand what I want

Comment: I got it, and as I recommended you should make response design if you have cut content